# python: exclude the commons from two dicts

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, set

Scenario:

I have two dicts, one is the factory_dct and the other is the sold_dct
The scenario is that, exclude all the items from the factory_dct that are present in the sold_dct
The difference is that, the factory dict has a `key` where as the sold_dct has the `key` inside the `day`

The following snippet takes a very long time when the data is huge, is there anyway I can optimise this?

```
def update_fctr_dct(factory_dct, sold_dct, day):
    for key in (set(factory_dct) & set(sold_dct)):
        if day in sold_dct[key]:
            sold_units = [d for d in factory_dct[key] for k, z in sold_dct[key][day].items() for z1 in z if
                 d['unit_id'] == z1['unit_id']]

            if sold_units:
               factory_dct[key] = [x for x in factory_dct[key] if x not in sold_units]
               factory_dct = {k: v for k, v in factory_dct.items() if v}

            else:
               print("No units sold this day")
```

Answer (score 0):

The culprit seems to be this triple-loop list comprehension:

```
sold_units = [d for d in factory_dct[key]
                for k, z in sold_dct[key][day].items() for z1 in z
                if d['unit_id'] == z1['unit_id']]
```

Here, you basically compare each unit produced in the factory with each unit sold that day. Instead, you should just create a set of sold `unit_id`s and see if the produced unit's ID is in that set.

```
def update_fctr_dct(factory_dct, sold_dct, day):
    for key in factory_dct:
        if key in sold_dct and day in sold_dct[key]:
            sold_ids = {z1["unit_id"] for z in sold_dct[key][day].values() for z1 in z}
            
            if sold_ids:
               factory_dct[key] = [x for x in factory_dct[key]
                                     if x["unit_id"] not in sold_ids]
               factory_dct = {k: v for k, v in factory_dct.items() if v}
```

You might also replace the last line with a single conditional `del factory_dct[key]`.

Comment: Which last line are you referring to?

Comment: @LeeKan The line `factory_dct = `, recreating the entire dict when you just have to remove (at most) one key.

Comment: If i did `delfactory_dct[key]` would it delete the key even if it wasnt empty?

Comment: @LeeKan Yes, that why I mean "conditional", i.e. `if not factory_dct[key]: del factory_dct[key]`

Comment: I get the error `for key in factory_dct:
RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration`

Comment: @LeeKan Ah, right. Use `for key in list(factory_dct):` then.

Comment: Would list be slower? Isn't tuple a better choice?

Comment: @LeeKan It does not matter at all, you just create it once so you don't iterate the same collection that you modify, but a copy of the keys. (I meant the very top-most outer loop)

Answer (score 0):

use `symmetric_difference()` on keys of your dict
or you can also use `^` operator with set.

```py
>>> a = {'1':1,'2':4}
>>> a
{'1': 1, '2': 4}
>>> b =  {'2':4, '3':9}
>>> b
{'2': 4, '3': 9}
>>> set(a)^set(b)
{'3', '1'}
```

Comment: [ref](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html#set-objects)

Comment: in my case the second dicts key is inside another key `day`.

Comment: @Lee Kan, then you need to track on every sold item, if some item sold then find and remove it from your `factory_dct`, this process is of constant time. rather than iterate through `factory_dct` and `sold_dct`.